# Adsense showing blank space depending on posts language

Tags: ads, adsense, non-english

I have a website with non - english posts. Just a couple of pages are in english. My adsense ads show properly in english posts but no ads show in non - english pages.

I thought it maight be that no ads relatet to that language are present in adsense but when i check english pages all ads are in the non - english language. So from the Adsense side there are ads served in the non - english language and the code works properly.

I want your help to understand:

- Why no ads from adsesnse are showing in the non - english posts
- How can i make it work that non - english pages show ads as the english pages.

Thank you.

A page in english where ads work properly: [Page English](http://www.1fakt.com/p/privacy-policy.html)

A page in non - english language whithout ads (or any page for that matter): [Page Non - English](http://www.1fakt.com/2017/01/horoskopi-ditor-e-premte-6-janar-2016.html)

Comment: I also face this problem.